# At fastboot, fastboot can connect to computer but adb cannot

Tags: reboot

The other way around happens when I reinstall cwm (yes I can reinstall cwm run fastboot, adb simply doesn't know it exist). When I do cwm

```
c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb reboot
```

See adb reboot works when I am on cwm. Adb recoqnize the device. After that?

```
c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
```

no devices.

```
c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.0-0-Z00A.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (15674 KB)...
OKAY [  0.780s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.876s]
finished. total time: 1.657s
```

Works just fine. Of course it's catch 2 2 because I want to do adb reboot recovery after that but cannot

Comment: What does `fastboot boot twrp-3.0.0-0-Z00A.img` do? You can use key combinations to boot into recovery mode. Isn't that the option for you?

Comment: Using key combination doesn't work. The only recovery I can get into is cwm and I do that after I install cwm. Basically I can do key combination, select recovery, and then boot again. However, it will go to bootloader.

Comment: so adb reboot recovery will reboot to recovery. Is there a fastboot command that's like that?

Comment: No there is not fastboot reboot recovery. The closest thing would be the command firelord ask you to perform and report the outcome.  fastboot boot twrp-3.0.0-0-Z00A.img On the previous commands it's: `adb shell`  then:  `su` lastly: `reboot recovery`